How to open a Reminders App reminder item using
I wrote a simpel app to integrate and work with Apple Reminders (CRUD).
The thing I struggle with is opening a Reminders item from my app using the calendarItemIdentifier. I get the identifier but I can’t build a valid URL or call Apple Reminders properly.
@Environment (\.openURL) private var openUrl

//...

let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminder://\(reminder.calendarItemIdentifier)")
openUrl(url!)

I get the following error message:
Failed to open URL x-apple-reminder://FB2D0D45-23E9-4851-A86E-636064BA6A39: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=277, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}


I don’t think Apple provides that functionality to developers. Most url schemes you find out there are private and your app will never make it passed review if they are used.

The error you are encountering

(Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814)

typically means that the system cannot find an application to handle the custom URL scheme (x-apple-reminder://). Unfortunately, Apple Reminders does not support opening specific reminders directly via a URL scheme, which is why this approrach is not working.
I Made a simple solution for you using EventKit. Please note that this is mostly copied code from 2 years ago, so there will probably be something deprecated.
Here's a way to list reminders, which you might have already implemented:
First of all you need to import the necessary frameworkss:
import EventKit

Then you need to request Access:
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        // Access granted
    } else {
        // Show some kind of alert or something, because you got denied.
    }
}

Fetch Reminders:
let predicate = eventStore.predicateForReminders(in: nil)
eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate) { reminders in
    for reminder in reminders ?? [] {
        print("Reminder: \(reminder.title ?? "No title")")
    }
}

For now, here's what you can do if you need to open the Apple Reminders app itself:
let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminder://")!
openUrl(url)

This will open the Reminders app, but not a specific reminder. I would try to wrap everything into a custom class or sth. so permission is asked on init. etc.. this should also make it easier to handle edge cases.

Thanks Karl! Yes I implemented all the cases you can cover using EventKit and could update this thread from my sample after some refactoring. But if it’s not possible to open a task directly then well… :-(

Unfortunatily I doubt the possibility of that. Maybee something with c works?
